# inline block image display for jQuery slide with Flexslider

Tags: jquery, html, css

Would someone please take a look at this for me?  I have been trying to piece the code together the last few days, and have been staring at it forever.  I cant get multiple images to stack next to each other, and also be responsive in size.  (see slide one)  I need them aligned horizontally, not vertically.  It does function properly in some browsers I have used, like Chrome.  I need it to work in all of them.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJKzs

```
<div id="tab">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
  <div id="panel">
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.arc-iris.com" ><img class="thumbnail" src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" style="max-width:30%;height:auto;" alt="" /></a>
          <a href="http://www.arc-iris.com" ><img class="thumbnail" src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" style="max-width:30%;height:auto;" alt="" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" width="800" height="200" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" width="800" height="200" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" width="800" height="200" alt="" />
        </li>
      </ul>


      <ol class="flex-control-nav">
        <li>Slide 1 Control</li>
        <li>Slide 2 Control</li>
        <li>Slide 3 Control</li>
        <li>Slide 4 Control</li>
      </ol>

    </div>
   </div>




#panel,#tab
{
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
display:none;
}

.flexslider,  .flexslider-controls  {  
  max-width:  800px;  
}

.flex-control-nav li  {  
  background:  #000;
  border-right:  solid #fff 1px;  
  color:  #fff;  
  cursor:  pointer;  
  float:  left;  
  margin:  0.09em 0 0 0; 
  padding:  1em 1.5em;    
  vertical-align:  middle;  
  width:  25%; 
  -webkit-box-sizing:  border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing:  border-box; 
  box-sizing:  border-box;  
}

.flex-control-nav li: hover {   
background: green;    
}

.flex-control-nav li: last-child  { 
   border:  none;  
}

.flex-control-nav .flex-active  {  
  background:  #ccc;  
  color:  #000;  
}

#panel a {  
      display: inline-block;    
}

/* Minified FlexSlider CSS with Chrome fix */
.flex-container a: active, 
.flexslider a:active, 
.flex-container a:focus, 
.flexslider a:focus
 {
    outline: 0;
}
.slides, 
.flex-control-nav, 
.flex-direction-nav
 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.flexslider {
    margin: auto;
}

.flexslider 
.slides>li
 {
    display: none;
    /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    */position: relative;
}
.flexslider .slides img
 {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.flex-pauseplay span
 {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.slides:after
 {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
html[xmlns] .slides {
    display: block;
}
* html .slides {
    height: 1%}
.no-js .slides>li:first-child {
    display: block;
}
.flexslider {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
}
.flex-viewport {
    max-height: 2000px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.loading .flex-viewport {
    max-height: 300px;
}
.flexslider .slides {
    zoom: 1;
}
.carousel li {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.flex-direction-nav {
    *height: 0;
}
.flex-direction-nav a {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: -20px 0 0;
    display: block;
    background-position:  0 0;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    background-position: 100% 0;
    right: -36px;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    left: -36px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next {
    opacity: .8;
    right: 5px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-prev {
    opacity: .8;
    left: 5px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next:hover, .flexslider:hover .flex-prev:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
    opacity: .3!important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
.flex-control-paging li a {
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    display: block;
    background: #666;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.flex-control-paging li a:hover {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-thumbs {
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    position: static;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    opacity: .7;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
}

.thumbnail {
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 5px;
}




$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tab").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

var $flexslider = $('.flexslider');
$flexslider.flexslider({
  slideshow: false,
  manualControls: ".flex-control-nav li",
  useCSS: false /* Chrome fix*/
});
```

Comment: Try: remove `#panel a {display: inline-block;}` completely from CSS.

Comment: In which browser is it not working properly?

Comment: The codepen is fixed, working in all browsers.  Thanks Martin, your answer was correct.